# Compare 2 large ActiveRecord relations for sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have 2 large `ActiveRecord::Relations` with 10s or 100s of thousands of User records each, let's call them `ar1` and `ar2`. I want to sort `ar1` so that all the records that also appear in `ar2` are placed at the front of `ar1`.

This is easy enough to to with `sort_by`, but because the number of records is so large, the `sort_by` takes over a minute in some cases to execute.

I figured my best bet was to try and sort the records this way through ActiveRecord, but I can't find any way to do this. Is there a way to accomplish this result quickly, using ActiveRecord or some other approach?

Thank you!

Edit:

Here's the sort code I was using: `ar1.sort_by { |e| ar2.index(e) || Float::INFINITY }`

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering ?

Comment: How would you compare 2 separate relations with `order`?

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided the queries and the sort code. It can be done in the AR space. You'll end up with an `OR` query and some custom fields that could control the ordering.

Comment: @xlembouras In my example, the 2 queries are both queries on the User table, generated with user-input data, so it's tough for me to add more detail. Will update the question with the sort code I was using

Comment: A few people are saying you might want to use order, they are right, it’s better to let the database handle ordering for large collections. If both relations are on the same model, and you’re on rails 5, you might want to try using ‘or’ to make it a single query. Here’s a blog post about it https://bigbinary.com/blog/rails-5-adds-or-support-in-active-record

Comment: @D-Nice Can you explain your question with an example

Answer (score 2):

I will start by saying that you don't really need `sort_by`!

You can achieve the same thing with:

```
ar1.sort_by { |e| ar2.index(e) || Float::INFINITY }
```

with an approach similar to:

```
result = ((ar2 & ar1) + ar1).uniq
```

Which is much faster.

Here is a simple benchmark to back this suggestion.

```
require 'benchmark'
ar1 = 100_000.times.map {|x|( 100_000_000 * rand).to_i }.uniq
ar2 = 100_000.times.map {|x|( 100_000_000 * rand).to_i }.uniq

puts ar1.size
puts ar2.size

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  result_2 = []
  result_1 = []
  x.report('sort') do
    result_2 = ar1.sort_by { |e| ar2.index(e) || Float::INFINITY }
    result_2.size
  end

  x.report('array') do
    result_1 = ((ar2 & ar1) + ar1).uniq
    result_1.size
  end

  puts result_1.size
  puts result_2.size
  puts result_1 == result_2
end
```

Gives some nice results

```
       user     system      total        real
sort 45.287331   0.012233  45.299564 ( 45.539641)
array  0.010782   0.004000   0.014782 (  0.014792)
```

I omitted some validation output.

Now for the ActiveRecord part.
Depending on the `ar2` collection size you can retrieve the ids and sort the second query by that. Given that `ar1 = first_query.order(first_order)`

```
ar2_ids = second_query.pluck(:id)

ar1 = first_query.order("FIELD(id, #{ar2_ids.join(',')}), first_order")
```

This will keep the `ar2` first and the others later.
You will need to investigate the size of `ar2` because depending on your database it may be suboptimal to provide an order query with some thousands of ids.

After some thought on the problem, I would choose the array manipulation approach to keep things simple. I wouldn't go for the database solutions because it would most probably mess up the readability of the queries, way too much.

It all depends on the details of your problem! I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I implemented your first suggestion, and it's about as slow as the `sort_by` solution (lots of records).

So I'm moving on to try and implement your second suggestion, but I'm having trouble understanding your thinking when creating a custom field with `concat`:

Can you elaborate a bit more on the purpose of this link? `select('users.*, CONCAT(ar2_1, ar2_2, ar2_3) as ar2_factor')`

Comment: @D-Nice I updated my answer with some benchmarks. Make sure that your two collections are evaluated when entering the Ruby sort stage to have a clear perception of the sort cost.

Answer (score 0):

For the information you gave, you could try this:

```rb
ids = ar2.ids
ar1.where(id: ids) + ar1.where.not(id: ids)
```

If you could tell us more: (e.g. what's the difference `ar1` and `ar2`), there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it possible we should use sql queries instead of ruby

```
active_users = User.where(sign_in_count: 1..) # ar1 query
inactive_users = User.where.not(id: active_users) #ar2 query
all_users = active_users | inactive_users # (ar1 + ar2).uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```sql
-- query1
SELECT * FROM table1

INTERSECT

-- query2
SELECT * FROM table2

UNION

-- query1
SELECT * FROM table1
```

#### Option 1

```rb
User.connection.unprepared_statement do
  User.find_by_sql """
    #{User.where(query1...).to_sql}

    INTERSECT

    #{User.where(query2...).to_sql}

    UNION

    #{User.where(query1...).to_sql}
  """
end
```

#### Option 2

```rb
(User.where(query1...) & User.where(query2...)) + User.where(query1...)
```